# creating an object property "relation/predicate" between individuals "instances" in protege?

Tags: ontology, protege

i am using protege 4 to create an ontology

if the question was not clear, here is an example :

Superclass is (thing)

Subclasses are as follow 
          (company) that has two data properties (company name) & (company abbreviation)
          (social network) 
          (service)

an instance of company class is (macintosh) that has two data properties (macintosh) & (MAC)

an instance of social network class is (facebook)

an instance of service class is (adsence)

1# i want to say that mac has a logo 
                 and  facebook has a logo
so, logo has to be a class ? and if , how to relate an individual to a class by a relation ? is this possible to do ?

2# how to relate two individuals by a relation in protege ?

Answer (score 1):

## 1

logo is a data property because logo itself has no properties and relations. It only has a value.

## 2

You will have to relate them while defining their classes first. Properties relate different classes. after that when you create an individual you will see a properties assertions panel. in this panel you can define relationships.

Answer (score 0):

### 2

In Protégé 5 you can relate two individuals by going to the Class Expression editor of a selected individual and type:

```
<property> some {<individual>}
```

or

```
<property> value <individual>
```

For instance

```
hasPet value Tibbs
```

Where `Tibbs` is a specific individual.

Reference: http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/class-expression-syntax/